# Jquery event on input change with specific class

Tags: jquery, forms, css, input, input-field

I need to trigger a function when an input text field with a specific CSS class is changed.

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="infoClient">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="Input" class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 control-label greenIfNotEmpty">Prénom</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Input" placeholder="">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                <i class="glyphicon  glyphicon-pencil"></i>
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <label for="disabledTextInput" class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 control-label greenIfNotEmpty">Nom famille</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <input type="text" id="disabledTextInput2" class="form-control" placeholder="">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                                <i class="glyphicon  glyphicon-pencil"></i>
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>



    $('input[type='text']').change(function() { ... });
```

This works for every input field,

```
$('input[type='text'] .greenIfNotEmpty').change(function() { ... });
```

is not working.

Can anyone help me on this ?

Comment: The space in CSS and jQuery selectors means "descendant", which excludes self. You're selecting some element in the input that has that class, which won't work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I feel dumb, I've attached class to Label instead of Input. Thanks a lot everybody.

Comment: Now you realized that. Welcome mate.

Comment: You should accept one of the answers, even if it's this one, by clicking on the green tick. This marks the problem solved in Stack Overflow (and you get points)

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this, demo in [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/User86745458/efezdcpv/)

**JS**

```
$('input:text.red').on('keyup', function() {
    alert('hello red')
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input type='text' class='red'/><br/>
<input type='text' class='yellow'/>
```

**CSS**

```
.red{
    background-color:red
}

.yellow {
    background-color:yellow
}
```

Comment: Did you include jquery lib yet? something like this   <script type='text/javascript' src='https//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>

Answer (score 0):

Try remove space between input and class name like so :

```
$('input[type='text'].cssClass').change(function() { ... });
```

Comment: Is it the input selector is true? i just copied from your code. And if the input has the class name, maybe you can just use something like `$('input.className')`

Comment: $('input.className') is not working either... I have a few input that as soon they are filled i want to make them green with class .success.... those input have css class greenIfNotEmpty...

Comment: Weird, it should work. is it the dom dynamically added into page?

Comment: Of course this never work because there is no classname on it. `greenIfNotEmpty` not attached on input itself. You want the input that next to `greenIfNotEmpty` i guess.